# Consecutive sequences not defined a priori in R

Tags: r, sequence

For each subject and each trial ID, I need to check that the unique *Current_Area_ID* is equal to the unique (*Next_Area_ID* - 1). If that is the case, in *NewColumn* (which is the output I want to obtain with R code) I will assign a value of 0 to that observation, if that is not the case, in the new column I will assign a value of 1. Both *Current_Area_ID* and *Next_Area_ID*  are columns of numeric class.

However, the tricky part is that I need to consider the unique values of the areas. In the following example, the numbers with ** represent the particular cases. When the number 3 is repeated,I can accept those cases and assign a value of 0 in the NewColumn because the Next_Area_ID that follows the unique value of 3 is 4. However, when we consider number 6, which is repeated but followed by number 8 (rather than number 7), then I need to assign a value of 1 for all the corresponding rows of number 6.

```
Current_Area_ID   Next_Area_ID  NewColumn
   1              8             1
   8              1             1
   1              1             1
   2              3             0
 **3**          **3**           0
 **3**          **3**           0
 **3**          **4**           0
   4              5             0
   5              6             0
 **6**          **6**           1
 **6**          **6**           1
 **6**          **8**           1
   7              9             1
   8              10            1
   9              11            1
   10             11            0
   10             1             1
   11             1             1
   11             1             1
   11             1             1
   1              1             1
   1              1             1
   1              1             1
```

Here is also a reproducible example:

```
Current_Area_ID <- c(1,8,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,10,10,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,6,8,8,10,11,12,12,11,13,1,1,1,1,1,4,5,6,6,8,8,6,6,8,9,9,11,10,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,6,7,7,7,6,7,8,8,11,11,12,13,13,13,1,5,1,5,6,7,7,6,1,1,1,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,9,10,9,11,11,12,1,1,1,4,5,6,7,7,9,10,10,10,11,12,12,12,12,12,11,12,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,4,5,6,6,8,8,9,10,11,11,11,1,11,5,3,3,3,6,5,6,8,9,8,6,6,8,9,10,5,3,3,4,1,1,1,1,5,6,6,7,8,8,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,12,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,4,6,6,7,8,8,8,9,9,10,10,10,6,4,3,6,7,7,3,3,3,5,6,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,3,6,5,3,6,6,6,6,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,1,12,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,5,6,6,7,7,9,9,10,11,11,11,1,6,4,5,4,6,7,6,6,5,1,1,3,3,4,3,4,5,5,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,5,5,6,7,6,7,7,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,1,6,4,4,5,5,6,5,1,1,1,1,1,7,1,7,8,8,9,9,10,12,13,13,14,15,1,9,1,1,1,1,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,11,12,13,13,14,1,1,1,7,6,4,4,4,6,7,7,7,7,4,5,4,4,1,1,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,6,7,8,8,9,11,11,12,14,1,11,6,1,1,7,8,9,11,12,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,10,11,12,12,11,12,13,1,1,1,5,6,7,7,10,12,7,5,6,1,1,1,1,4,4,5,6,5,5,6,7,7,10,11,12,12,13,1,1,5,1,1,1,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,8,8,9,9,9,10,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,1,5,5,6,7,7,7,9,10,11,11,12,12,11,11,12,1,1,7,4,5,7,7,9,7,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,5,6,6,6,8,8,10,10,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,9,10,9,10,9,10,11,11,1,1,1,1,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,9,9,10,11,11,12,12,12,1,12,9,6,5,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,8,9,10,10,11,11,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,9,10,11,11,11,1,5,3,4,5,6,6,8,9,10,6,6,3,5,1,1,1,1,3,4,4,4,5,6,8,8,9,10,11,1,1,3,4,5,6,9,9,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,4,4,4,3,4,6,6,6,9,9,10,10,11,12,12,1,6,4,1,1,1,1,5,6,6,7,8,8,10,11,12,13,12,13,1,8,1,5,8,10,11,10,10,7,10,7,6,1,1,1,1,1,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,11,12,12,13,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,4,3,3,4,4,5,6,5,6,6,8,9,9,10,11,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,8,9,9,10,11,10,11,11,11,1,1,1,9,1,1,1,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,9,10,11,11,12,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,10,1,1,5,1,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,5,6,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,12,11,10,11,12,12,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,4,5,4,3,4,4,5,6,6,10,10,10,12,12,12,11,10,12,12,12,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,10,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,12,12,12,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,4,4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,12,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,4,5,5,4,5,6,6,8,9,10,11,11,1,11,11,11,1,1,4,4,5,5,6,7,9,9,10,11,12,12,12,11,12,1,1)
Next_Area_ID <- c(8,1,1,3,3,3,4,5,6,6,6,8,9,10,10,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,6,8,8,10,11,12,12,11,13,1,1,NA,1,1,4,5,6,6,8,8,6,6,8,9,9,11,10,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,6,7,7,7,6,7,8,8,11,11,12,13,13,13,1,5,1,5,6,7,7,6,NA,1,1,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,9,10,9,11,11,12,NA,1,1,4,5,6,7,7,9,10,10,10,11,12,12,12,12,12,11,12,1,1,NA,1,1,3,4,4,5,6,6,8,8,9,10,11,11,11,1,11,5,3,3,3,6,5,6,8,9,8,6,6,8,9,10,5,3,3,4,NA,1,1,1,5,6,6,7,8,8,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,12,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,4,6,6,7,8,8,8,9,9,10,10,10,6,4,3,6,7,7,3,3,3,5,6,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,3,6,5,3,6,6,6,6,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,1,12,1,1,NA,1,1,4,4,5,6,6,7,7,9,9,10,11,11,11,1,6,4,5,4,6,7,6,6,5,1,1,3,3,4,3,4,5,5,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,1,1,1,1,1,NA,1,1,4,5,5,6,7,6,7,7,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,1,6,4,4,5,5,6,5,NA,1,1,1,1,7,1,7,8,8,9,9,10,12,13,13,14,15,1,9,NA,1,1,1,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,11,12,13,13,14,1,1,1,7,6,4,4,4,6,7,7,7,7,4,5,4,4,1,1,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,NA,1,1,6,6,7,8,8,9,11,11,12,14,1,11,6,1,1,7,8,9,11,12,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,10,11,12,12,11,12,13,1,1,1,5,6,7,7,10,12,7,5,6,NA,1,1,1,4,4,5,6,5,5,6,7,7,10,11,12,12,13,1,1,5,NA,1,1,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,8,8,9,9,9,10,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,1,5,5,6,7,7,7,9,10,11,11,12,12,11,11,12,1,1,7,4,5,7,7,9,7,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,5,6,6,6,8,8,10,10,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,9,10,9,10,9,10,11,11,1,1,NA,1,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,9,9,10,11,11,12,12,12,1,12,9,6,5,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,8,9,10,10,11,11,1,1,1,NA,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,9,10,11,11,11,1,5,3,4,5,6,6,8,9,10,6,6,3,5,NA,1,1,1,3,4,4,4,5,6,8,8,9,10,11,1,1,3,4,5,6,9,9,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,4,4,4,3,4,6,6,6,9,9,10,10,11,12,12,1,6,4,NA,1,1,1,5,6,6,7,8,8,10,11,12,13,12,13,1,8,1,5,8,10,11,10,10,7,10,7,6,1,1,1,1,1,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,11,12,12,13,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,4,3,3,4,4,5,6,5,6,6,8,9,9,10,11,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,8,9,9,10,11,10,11,11,11,1,1,1,9,1,1,1,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,9,10,11,11,12,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,10,1,1,5,1,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,5,6,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,12,11,10,11,12,12,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,4,5,4,3,4,4,5,6,6,10,10,10,12,12,12,11,10,12,12,12,1,1,1,12,1,1,1,1,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,10,11,11,11,12,1,1,1,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,12,12,12,1,1,1,6,12,1,1,4,4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,12,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,4,5,5,4,5,6,6,8,9,10,11,11,1,11,11,11,12,1,4,4,5,5,6,7,9,9,10,11,12,12,12,11,12,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Subject <- rep(c(1,2), each=500)
Trial <- rep(1:25,each=20)
DataFrame <- data.frame(cbind(Current_Area_ID,Next_Area_ID,Subject,Trial))
```

In order to create *NewColumn* I tried to use:

```
library(dplyr)

DataFrame<-{DataFrame %>%
    group_by(Subject, Trial) %>% 
    mutate(NewColumn = ifelse(
    unique(DataFrame$Current_Area_ID) == unique(DataFrame$Next_Area_ID - 1),
    0, 1
))}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not clear how you get `NewColumn` (for me at least)

Comment: NewColumn is what I need to obtain with the R code.

Comment: Please try and explain better how you obtain `NewColumn`. It is not clear

Comment: NewColumn is the output I would like to obtain after I run the code in R. Code that at the moment doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I will try to ask you one more time. How is the `NewColumn` (which I know that it is the output that you would like to obtain) calculated? Explain the steps in calculating `NewColumn`. I know that it is your expected output but we still need to have a clear understanding of the logic behind it.

Comment: *NewColumn* needs to have values of 0 or 1. 0 when the Current_Area_ID and Next_Area_ID are consecutive (e.g., 1, 2; 2, 3; 3, 4; 4, 5; 5, 6; etc.). 1 when the Current_Area_ID and Next_Area_ID are not consecutive (e.g., 1, 3; 3, 6; 2, 5; 4, 8; 7, 9; etc.). However, when Current_Area_ID has a repetition of numbers, then we need to consider the last number in the series. If the last number in Current_Area_ID is followed by a consecutive number in Next_Area_ID (e.g., 33333, 4) then we give value 0, if not (e.g., 33333, 5), a value of 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A potential solution using package `data.table`:

If I understand correctly, based on your comments, you can have different values for same Current_Area_ID/Subject/Trial. You need your `NewColumn` to be either 0 if it is `Current_Area_ID` + 1 or if it is same as `Current_Area_ID` but it is `Current_Area_ID` + 1 on some row directly after the (repeated) same value.
We still need to do it by `Subject` and by `Trial`.

```
# checking DataFrame is ordered by Subject and Trial:
all(DataFrame==DataFrame[order(DataFrame$Subject, DataFrame$Trial), ], na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] TRUE

# turning DataFrame into a data.table (as previously done) and applying for
# each unique Subject/Trial a function which split the 2 "Area Column" 
# according to unique consecutive Current_Value and assign 0 or 1 depending on whether the constraints are fulfilled:

library(data.table)
setDT(DataFrame)[, NewColumn:= unlist(lapply(split(.SD, rep(seq_along(rle(Current_Area_ID)$values), rle(Current_Area_ID)$lengths)), 
                                             function(spdf) {
                           spdf[, diff:=Next_Area_ID-Current_Area_ID]
                           wh1 <- tail(which(spdf$diff==1), 1)
                           # Initiate the Newcolumn to 1 for every row
                           spnc <- rep(1, nrow(spdf)) 
                           # if there is a Next_Area consecutive to Current, put everything before to 0, 
                           # but only if it is either same as current, NA or consecutive to current
                           if(length(wh1)) spnc[1:wh1][is.na(spdf$diff[1:wh1]) | (spdf$diff[1:wh1] %in% c(0, 1))] <- 0
                           spnc
                                             }))
                             , by=c("Subject", "Trial"), .SDcols=c("Current_Area_ID", "Next_Area_ID")]
```

***Check for the rows you mentionned:***

```
cbind(Row=c(29:31, 35:40, 49:51), DataFrame[c(29:31, 35:40, 49:51)])
#    Row Current_Area_ID Next_Area_ID Subject Trial NewColumn
# 1:  29               5            5       1     2         0
# 2:  30               5            6       1     2         0
# 3:  31               5            8       1     2         1
# 4:  35              10           12       1     2         1
# 5:  36              11           12       1     2         0
# 6:  37              12           11       1     2         1
# 7:  38              12           13       1     2         0
# 8:  39              11            1       1     2         1
# 9:  40              13            1       1     2         1
#10:  49               6            8       1     3         1
#11:  50               8            6       1     3         1
#12:  51               8            6       1     3         1
```

***Comparing to @NickKennedy results:*** everything is the same, except for `NA`:

```
all(as.data.frame(data_proc[, 2:6])==as.data.frame(DataFrame), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] TRUE
```

Looking at `NA`s:

```
sum(is.na(data_proc[, 2:6])) 
# [1] 34
sum(is.na(DataFrame))
# [1] 17
```

Comparisons of the rows that are not identical because of NAs:

```
diffNA <- which(rowSums(is.na(data_proc[, 2:6])) != rowSums(is.na(DataFrame)))
head(as.data.frame(data_proc[diffNA, 2:6]))
#   Current_Area_ID Next_Area_ID Subject Trial NewColumn
#1                1           NA       1     3        NA
#2                7           NA       1     5        NA
#3               11           NA       1     6        NA
#4                1           NA       1     7        NA
#5                3           NA       1     9        NA
#6                1           NA       1    10        NA
head(as.data.frame(DataFrame[diffNA]))
#  Current_Area_ID Next_Area_ID Subject Trial NewColumn
#1               1           NA       1     3         1
#2               7           NA       1     5         1
#3              11           NA       1     6         1
#4               1           NA       1     7         1
#5               3           NA       1     9         1
#6               1           NA       1    10         1
```

---

**Previous answer/edit:**

It checks for each `Subject`/`Trial`/`Current_Area_ID` if any `Next_Area_ID` satisfies the condition *`Current_Area_ID` is equal to the (`Next_Area_ID` - 1)* and assign `1` or `0` to `Newcolumn` accordingly. We use `%in%` to avoid getting NA when `Next_Area_ID` is `NA`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DataFrame)[, NewColumn:=as.integer(!any((Current_Area_ID-Next_Area_ID+1) %in% 0)), by=c("Current_Area_ID", "Subject", "Trial")]
DataFrame[1:20]
#    Current_Area_ID Next_Area_ID Subject Trial NewColumn
# 1:               1            8       1     1        1
# 2:               8            1       1     1        1
# 3:               1            1       1     1        1
# 4:               2            3       1     1        0
# 5:               3            3       1     1        0
# 6:               3            3       1     1        0
# 7:               3            4       1     1        0
# 8:               4            5       1     1        0
# 9:               5            6       1     1        0
#10:               6            6       1     1        1
#11:               6            6       1     1        1
#12:               6            8       1     1        1
#13:               7            9       1     1        1
#14:               8           10       1     1        1
#15:               9           10       1     1        0
#16:              10           11       1     1        0
#17:              10           11       1     1        0
#18:              11           11       1     1        1
#19:              11            1       1     1        1
#20:              11            1       1     1        1
```

**EDIT:**

If you need the last non `NA` value to be the `Current_Area_ID`+1 and all others to be either the same number as current or `NA`:

```
setDT(DataFrame)[, NewColumn:=as.integer(!(tail(na.omit(Current_Area_ID-Next_Area_ID+1), 1) %in% 0 & all(head(na.omit(Current_Area_ID-Next_Area_ID), -1) %in% 0))), by=c("Current_Area_ID", "Subject", "Trial")]
```

Comment: Cath, this is a great solution! Thanks! The only issue is that at times *NewColumn* has a value of NA when it should be 1 (because *Current_Area_ID* and *Next_Area_ID* are not consecutive), and a value of 0 when *Current_Area_ID* or *Next_Area_ID* have NA as value. Do you know how to solve this? Many thanks.

Comment: @dede Thanks, I modified my solution to take into account `NA`s, sorry I didn't notice there were any. Let me know if you're getting the expected results (from what I've checked, it seems to give the expected output)

Comment: Cath, the NA solution works. However, if for example you display the first 50 lines of *DataFrame* you will see that there is something going wrong. For example, in row 31, *Current_Area_ID* is equal to 5 and *Next_Area_ID* to 8, which means that they are not consecutive, but in*NewColumn* it has been assigned a value of 0. The same happens for example also to rows 37, 39, 50.

Comment: @dede but in row 30, you have Next_Area_ID equal to 6, with same Current_Area (5), Subject and Trial, which fulfills the constraints, hence the `0`. Same for row 37, you have 13 in row 38 with same other values. And row 39, Next_Area_Id is equal to 12 in row 36. Or did I get your constraint wrong ?

Comment: row 30 works perfectly, as you described, because Current_Area and Next_Area are consecutive. However, in row 31 Current_Area = 5 and Next_Area = 8 (instead of 6). In row 37, Current_Area = 12 and Next_Area = 11 (instead of 13). In row 39 Current_Area = 11 and Next_Area = 1 (instead of 12). In row 50, Current_Area = 8 and Next_Area = 6 (instead of 9). In all these examples, there should be a value of 1 in *NewColumn*, because Current_Area and New_Area are not consecutive.

Comment: @dede and should there be a value of 0 or 1 in row 29 and 30 (for example) (my code is based on the fact that for same Trial, Subject and Current_Area_ID, all lines are either 1 or 0)

Comment: For rows 29 and 30 it is correct a value of 0, because although 5 is repeated, the next number to appear as Next_Area is 6, which holds the 'consecutive' assumption I need. I hope it helps to clarify.

Comment: @dede have you tried the latest solution (which appears first in my answer)? Is it working for you?

Comment: the issue is that the first line of your code `all(DataFrame==DataFrame[order(DataFrame$Subject, DataFrame$Trial), ], na.rm=TRUE)` returns FALSE. I have tried to use `arrange(DataFrame,Subject,Trial)` but still it returns FALSE.

Comment: Just order DataFrame or try it as it is, I don't think it would be a problem

Comment: your solution works even without the first line of code being true. Thanks very much! Could I please ask you some explanation of the code? When you create `NewColumn` and use `.SD`, is it correct that we are applying the split function to the list sequence for each group? If it is the case, which group are we considering? Or this is just to set up groups that will be defined later on (`.SDcols=c("Current_Area_ID", "Next_Area_ID"). Also, why we need to use `rep`? Other question, when you create the new variable `wh1` why we use ‘tail’? and what does the value 1 after the comma refers to?

Comment: last two questions. I know you tried to explain it by word, but I am having difficulties understanding what `[1:wh1]` refers to, and also what does the c(0, 1) do. Many many thanks for your solution and help!

Comment: [1:wh1] is to put everything to 0 till indice with next area = current+1 (this indice is wh1) but only if from 1 to wh1, everything is either NA, 0 or 1 (for the difference between next and current). I hope it is clearer, let me know if it is not

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
# First define a function to check whether the constraints are met
# This assumes that any rows with consecutive `Current_Area_ID` and `Next_Area_ID`
# should be zero, and any preceeding rows within that group where
# `Current_Area_ID` == `Next_Area_ID` should also be zero.
# Rows with `NA` as `Next_Area_ID` will come out as `NA`
check_areas <- function(cur, nxt) {
  ok <- nxt == cur + 1
  if (any(ok, na.rm = TRUE) && min(which(ok)) > 1L) {
    prev <- 1:min(which(ok) - 1)
    ok[prev] <- nxt[prev] == cur[prev]
  }
  as.integer(!ok)
}
# Now add a running sequence number to the data, `group_by` that and then
# add in the new column
data_proc <- DataFrame %>%
  mutate(Seq = cumsum(c(1, .$Current_Area_ID[-1] != .$Current_Area_ID[-nrow(DataFrame)] |
                          .$Subject[-1] != .$Subject[-nrow(DataFrame)] |
                          .$Trial[-1] != .$Trial[-nrow(DataFrame)]))) %>%
  group_by(Seq) %>%
  mutate(NewColumn = check_areas(Current_Area_ID, Next_Area_ID)) %>%
  select(-Seq)
```

Note this differs to @Cath's answer in some rows such as row 37, where I return a 1 (as suggested by @dede's comment

> row 30 works perfectly, as you described, because Current_Area and
>   Next_Area are consecutive. However, in row 31 Current_Area = 5 and
>   Next_Area = 8 (instead of 6). In row 37, Current_Area = 12 and
>   Next_Area = 11 (instead of 13). In row 39 Current_Area = 11 and
>   Next_Area = 1 (instead of 12). In row 50, Current_Area = 8 and
>   Next_Area = 6 (instead of 9). In all these examples, there should be a
>   value of 1 in NewColumn, because Current_Area and New_Area are not
>   consecutive.

Comment: Thank you for this solution - it seems to work! However, I have some questions to better understand the solution, if you don't mind. In the first part of the code, we are asking R to check whether any value resulting from *ok* is true and at the same time if the minimum index to be true is greater than 1. If that is the case, then we ask to create the variable *prev*. I am not clear about how *prev* is calculated and what the next line of code `ok[prev] <- nxt[prev] == cur[prev]` is doing. Also, are we asking to have all variables as integer except *ok*?

Comment: In the second part of the code, I am not clear about what `.$Current_Area_ID[-nrow(DataFrame)]`, `.$Subject[-nrow(DataFrame)]` and `.$Trial[-nrow(DataFrame)]` mean. Also, in the last line of code, we are asking to drop the variable *Seq*?

Comment: @dede in the function, `prev` is the index of every entry for that `Subject`/`Trial`/`Current_Area_ID` section that is before the first one with consecutive `Next_Area_ID`. Any of the rows in that range where `Current_Area_ID == Next_Area_ID` are marked as ok.

Comment: @dede regarding the second question, I noticed that there were blocks within a `Subject`/`Trial` where the `Current_Area_ID` went up and then back down again. I'm not sure if this is correct, but I thought it was intended that each contiguous block of `Subject`/`Trial`/`Current_Area_ID` should be handled separately. However, `group_by` will group rows together even if the `Current_Area_ID` is non-contiguous. I've therefore created a `Seq` variable which increases every time any of `Subject`/`Trial`/`Current_Area_ID` change. This then is dropped at the end.

Comment: @NickKennedy Note that in row 37 my edit2 was supposed to return 1... ;-) Actually I had a typo in my code and now it's working exactly like it should, giving same results as your code:-)

Comment: @NickKennedy sorry to be a pain, but when I run the code with my real data, it gives me this error: `Error: incompatible size (114755), expecting 25 (the group size) or 1`. Why would that be? Thanks.

Comment: @dede what do you get if you run a `traceback`? At what stage do you get the error? (i.e. Trim off commands from the piped series of commands until the error doesn't occur - the error is in the next step. )

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Sotos that it's not 100% clear to me how you want to get `NewColumn`, but I looked at what you provided and tried to reason it out, and I think this might do what you want...

```
NewColumn <- rep(1, length(Current_Area_ID))
for(i in length(Current_Area_ID):1) {

  if(!is.na(Next_Area_ID[i])){

    if(Current_Area_ID[i] == (Next_Area_ID[i]-1)) NewColumn[i] <- 0

    if(!is.na(Next_Area_ID[i+1])){
      if(Current_Area_ID[i + 1] == Current_Area_ID[i] &
             NewColumn[i + 1] == 0) NewColumn[i] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that my solution provides the same results as Edit 2 from above. Run both to check `FALSE %in% (DataFrame$NewColumn == NewColumn)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please find this possible solution:

from your data you create a primary key to distinct all different case:

```
DataFrame$PK <- paste(DataFrame[,1],DataFrame[,2],DataFrame[,3],DataFrame[,4], sep = "_")
```

Then you check if any row in each different case satisfied your condition (Next_Area_ID-1 == Current_Area_ID) and create a table of result

```
library(plyr)
result_table     <- ddply(unique(DataFrame), 
                 .(PK),
                 summarise, 
                 test = any((Next_Area_ID-1) == Current_Area_ID) ,
                 .parallel = F )
```

then you merge the results and the original data according the primary key, compute NewColumn and clean up the DF:

```
# creation of NewColumn
DataFrame$NewColumn <- 1
# assignation of 0 if needed
DataFrame$NewColumn[DataFrame$test] <- 0
# clean up 
DataFrame <-DataFrame[,c(-1,-6)] 
# quick test                                      
DataFrame[DataFrame$NewColumn == 0,]
```

It seems to work